# Messaging component is super slow

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a messaging component that makes it possible to write messages with another user in my system. The problem is when I open the component the site gets super slow and it takes up to 15 seconds before the messages are loaded. What could I do different in the code to make it work as it should?

```
allMessages() {
    return this.messages.concat(this.uploadingMessages);
}
```

```
<ng-container #messageList *ngFor="let m of allMessages(); let i = index; trackBy: trackByMessageId">
    <div *ngIf="case !== null" [class.unread]="case.hasReadUntilTimestamp < m.timestamp && !m.sender.isMe && !m.setRead">


    <div class="newMessage">
        <div class="newMessage__line"></div>
        <div class="newMessage__line"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row messageAndHeader line" *ngIf="allMessages()[i - 1]?.sender.id !== m.sender.id; else elseBlock">
    <div class="row messageInfo">
        <div class="profileImg">
            <img *ngIf="m.sender.profileImageUrl !== null" [src]="m.sender.profileImageUrl" />
 *ngIf="m.sender.profileImageUrl === null">
        </div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the correct markup. There seems to be some issue with the markup. Also, if possible please share some sample data to work with.

Comment: One of the reason that I clearly see is that you're calling `allMessages()` in an `*ngIf` which will call the function at every change detection cycle.

Comment: Yea, don't call methods like that in your angular template. Get the data in your component, store it in a variable, and use that variable in your template.

Answer (score 2):

In angular DOM will be refreshed for all events, so here allMessages() will be called repeatedly, SO do this operation in NgOnInit() assign to one variable like below

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.allMesage = this.messages.concat(this.uploadingMessages);
}
```

and in compoent.html modify the code as below

```
<ng-container #messageList *ngFor="let m of allMessage; let i = index; trackBy: trackByMessageId">
```

if the messages are getting populated after making API call then add async pipe like below

```
<ng-container #messageList *ngFor="let m of allMessage | async; let i = index; trackBy: trackByMessageId">
```

And remove calling method In ngif

```
<div class="row messageAndHeader line" *ngIf="allMessage[i - 1]?.sender.id !== m.sender.id; else elseBlock">
```

If it is api call modify the code in ngOnInit() like below

```
ngOnInit(){
apiCall.subscribe(data=>{
 this.allMesage = data.messages.concat(data.uploadingMessages);
},
error=>{
console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: I'd suggest also mentioning the `*ngIf`.

Comment: Adding ngif depends on from where the data is getting populated?

Comment: Yes @cerbus your right, should remove calling method in ngif also instead use varibale name

Comment: I've changed the code as you said ajaykumpar mp but now my messages doesnt appear at all, and i do not get any errors in the console. My code now looks like:

 this.allMesage = this.messages.concat(this.uploadingMessages);

HTML:

<ng-container #messageList *ngFor="let m of allMessage; let i = index; trackBy: trackByMessageId">

and then i changed all the function calls to "m" instead.

Comment: How  are you fetching messages,  is this a api call?

Comment: Yes it is an api call.

Comment: @RobinKöhn i have edited my code to get data from api call,plz check